# Float TryParse not working as expected from string

Tags: c#

I tried several examples/ways of doing it and no expected result.

I store in a string

```
// Contains in my case "EUR849.00" so I want to get only the proper number.
string properPrice = price[0].Substring(3);
```

Now, I try to parse this string `849.00`into float and I expect to have this format `849,00`.

I tried several examples (specific invariant culture, replacing the `.` with `,` and then parsing using `float.Parse` but it doesn't work).

The way I'm doing it is :

```
float.TryParse(properPrice, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out floatPrice);
```

The result is **`84900.0`**. 
Any suggestions? 
Tx.

Comment: Try using double.TryParse, or add 'f' at the end of your string

Comment: Cannot reproduce, I've got 849.0. Try playing with your last expression in watch window (change properPrice to the corresponding literal string)

Comment: You mean to change the string into `849,00` and then trying to parse? Also tried it. :-?

Comment: *Now, I try to parse this string 849.00 into float and I expect to have this format 849,00.* Floats don't have a format. Are you trying to print out a float and you're wondering why it's printing `.` instead of `,` ?

Comment: Float doesn't have `,` ?

Comment: Using float instead of decimal for money is a bad idea, since it can't even represent 0.00 exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need specify the culture when parsing when the format of the string is not using the current culture's formatting. So if your culture uses a decimal instead of a comma you don't need to specify it.

If your current culture uses decimals, then you need to specify a culture that uses commas, when you write out the value. In the example below I have picked the German culture, which uses commas.

Also, it looks like you are dealing with currency, so you should decimal instead of float. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx

```
string val = "EUR849.00";
decimal num = Decimal.Parse(val.Substring(3));

string expected = num.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"));

Console.WriteLine(expected);
```

**UPDATE**
With a float:

```
string val = "EUR849.00";
float num = Single.Parse(val.Substring(3));

string expected = num.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"));

Console.WriteLine(expected);
```

Comment: Then just stop after line 2

Comment: Updated my answer to include float