# How to multiply two numbers and get the SUM every two numbers is multiply?

Tags: c#, .net

Good day everyone! Hope this work. I have to 2 textboxes and I convert it to integer the num1 and num2. I want to display it into textSubtotal. For example 10 * 10 = 100. I want to multiply another 2 numbers the value is 20 * 20 = 400. Add it to 100 so the answer will be 100 + 400 = 500. But the problem is I received an error in this line `textSubtotal.Text = Convert.ToString(float.Parse(textSubtotal.Text) + sum)` Input string was not in a correct format. Can somebody help me regarding to my problem?

```
private void buttonOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            float num1, num2, product = 0, sum = 0; 
            num1 = float.Parse(textPrice.Text); 
            num2 = float.Parse(textQuantity.Text); 
            product = num1 * num2; sum = sum + product;
            textSubtotal.Text = Convert.ToString(float.Parse(textSubtotal.Text) + sum);
}
```

Comment: You need to [learn how to debug](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) to look at what `textSubtotal.Text` contains. Then investigate using [`Float.TryParse`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710380/) instead of `Float.parse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to struggle with Textbox string conversions to do that. Use a private field:

```
private float subTotal = 0;    // this would be a field in your class

private void buttonOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  float num1 = float.Parse(textPrice.Text); 
  float num2 = float.Parse(textQuantity.Text); 
  subTotal += num1 * num2;

  textSubtotal.Text = subTotal;
}
```

You should check that the two fields contain actual numeric values (see [`float.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2)). Also, consider using [`decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netframework-4.7.2) (not `float`) for this kind of calculations.

Comment: Appreciate sir you're my savior.. I'm so happy that someone like you are here to help people like me struggle on coding.